# How to specifc exec on volumeMount

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

We have OpenShift 3.9 running in our Cluster.
I currently am trying out the Pipeline capabilities of OpenShift. It turns out the default recipies for Jenkins are not working.
The problem is that the `volumeMount` specified in the *dc* leads to a `noexec` mount in the Container. When the Jenkins git plugin is then trying to execute its ssh wrapper in `/var/lib/jenkins` it of course fails.

The config they use in the *dc* is:

```
  volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: jenkins-data
```

and then mount it via:

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/jenkins
          name: jenkins-data
```

I could not find any option to configure which mount options are to be used in the container.
Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at a persistent volume instead of emptyDir, at least see if that solves the issue. I didn't see anything obviosiy about `noexec` when looking at the api docs for emptyDir.

Comment: I also `PV` is good idea than `emptyDir`, because `emptyDir` can not adjust the mount option, refer [emptyDir with medium: Memory mounts a tmpfs volume without nosuid,nodev,noexec](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48912)  at now.